# how can I sort my collection in java so that the given element can be found on the first index?

Tags: java, sorting, collections, java-8

I have a collection of custom structures in Java:

```
private List<CustomStructure> items = new ArrayList<>();
```

I also have a method, that when called on a single object `CustomStructure` - returns the value of one of the fields. This method is called `.getDirectName()`.

I need a method that goes through my list `items` and puts on the first index the element which direct name equals to some input String.

So if the list contains the following elements:

```
first
 |
  --> getDirectName() -> one
second
 |
  --> getDirectName() -> two
third
 |
  --> getDirectName() -> three
fourth
 |
  --> getDirectName() -> four
```

and the method gets `three` as an input param, the result should be:

```
third first second fourth
```

What's the most efficient way to do it in java 8?

Comment: What if there are several items with given name?

Comment: I think the best way would be to put them upfront then, but for the moment let's pretend this situation never happens

Comment: Probably the same way as in Java 7 or earlier. Don't assume that any fancy Java 8 stuff is always useful.

Comment: Apart from relocating specified item to first, would you like to sort other items as well?

Comment: @MehdiJavan no, I do not care about other items :)

Answer (score 2):

If there might be multiple occurrences of the item or you just like fancy Java 8 features, you can use

```
list.sort(Comparator.comparing(itemToBeMovedToFront::equals).reversed());
```

(without `reversed()`, it would move them to the end).

However, if there can be at most one occurrence, the Java 2 variant

```
Collections.rotate(list.subList(0, list.indexOf(itemToBeMovedToFront)+1), 1);
```

might be more efficient.

Adapting them to use a property of the list element yields

```
list.sort(Comparator.comparing(
  (CustomStructure cs) -> cs.getDirectName().equals(dirNameToBeMovedToFront)).reversed());
```

for the first variant

or

```
IntStream.range(0, list.size())
    .filter(ix -> list.get(ix).getDirectName().equals(dirNameToBeMovedToFront))
    .findAny()
    .ifPresent(index -> Collections.rotate(list.subList(0, index+1), 1));
```

for the second. Now, even the second variant uses Java 8 features, as finding an element with a certain property was not that neat before Java 8…

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void relocateToTop(List<CustomStructure> items, String directName) {
    for (Iterator<CustomStructure> iterator = items.iterator(); iterator.hasNext(); ) {
        CustomStructure item = iterator.next();
        if(Objects.equals(item.getDirectName(), directName)) {
            iterator.remove();
            items.add(0, item);
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

**[EDIT]**

Remember to always use `Iterator` to iterate through your `List` even when you are going to remove one of them because in case your list is of type of `LinkedList` iterating using a regular `for` and getting items by their index makes order of your algorithm O(n^2). For example something like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
    System.out.println(list.get(i));
```

If the list is a `LinkedList` then in every calling of `get` method we have another loop from the head of the `LinkedList` to reach the i-th element because unlike `ArrayList`, `LinkedList` does not store elements by their index.

Comment: You'll probably encounter a `ConcurrentModificationException` if you move and add at the same time.

Comment: @RealSkeptic No, because I return after I found the item. Of course, if there are several items to remove the code must change.

Comment: How does iterating with a regular for over a LinkedList result in a O(n^2) algorithm?

Comment: @toongeorges Actually, by regular `for` I mean `for(int i = 0; i < list.size();i++) doSomethingOn(list.get(i));`. I should have mentioned it explicitly.

Comment: @toongeorges I updated my answer and add some more explanation. Is it sufficient?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using java 8 (as implied), you always have the `Stream::filter` method to find your things.

```
final List<CustomStructur> filtered = items.stream()
        .filter(item -> givenName.equals(item.getDirectName()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

items.removeAll(filtered);
items.addAll(0, filtered);
```